# Como "ler" mensagens de retorno ASP.NET CORE WEB API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-web-api

Vejo aqui inúmeras perguntas sobre como criar retorno personalizado em uma WEB API usando ASP.NET Core. Minha dúvida, além desta é o lado cliente, como essa mensagem pode ser lida no aplicativo que vai consumir os serviços. 
Por exemplo: o usuário esta cadastrando um novo item em um banco de dados onde a descrição não pode ser repetida. Como devolver uma mensagem e como ler esta mensagem para apresenta-la ao usuário, caso ele tente informar um item que já exista?

Eu estou tentando desta maneira:

**MODEL**

```
namespace ComandinhaAPI.Models
{
   public class TipoCardapio
   {
       [Key]
       public int TipoId { get; set; }
       public string Descricao { get; set; }
   }
}
```

**API ASP.NET - Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] TipoCardapio tipoCardapio)
{
        if(tipoCardapio==null)
            return BadRequest("Necessário informar os dados do tipo!");

        string nomeUpper = tipoCardapio.Descricao.ToUpper();
        tipoCardapio.Descricao = nomeUpper;

        if(_tRepositorio.BuscaPorDescricao(tipoCardapio.Descricao) != null)

            return BadRequest("Já existe um tipo com essa descrição!");

        _tRepositorio.Add(tipoCardapio);
```

**CLIENTE - WINDOWS FORMS - HTTPCLIENT**

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
   var serializedTipo = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tipoCardapio);
   var content = new StringContent(serializedTipo, Encoding.UTF8, 
   "application/json");
   var result = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content);

   if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Falha ao salvar o Tipo do Cardápio : \n" +
                        result.StatusCode.ToString() + " : " + 
                        result.ReasonPhrase.ToString(), "Tipos do Cardápio", 
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
   }
}
GetAllTipoCardapios();
```

Não sei se é esta a maneira correta, mas ao ver a aplicação rodar em modo debug consigo ler as mensagens retornadas no "result", porém não consigo exibi-las ao usuário.

Existe outro meio para retornar e ler as respostas da API ?

Comment: É possível inserir seu objeto, pra que possa elaborar uma resposta?

Comment: @Connection Desculpe minha ignorância, mas o que seria o objeto? 
Eu editei a pergunta, adicionei a ela o meu MODEL.

O que desejo é ler a resposta da API, se ela me retorna um 404 - Not Found. E junto com essa mensagem vem uma mensagem personalizada: Tipo não existe no cadastro.

Comment: Seu objeto seria o `TipoCardapio` que recebe por parametro. se você recebeu um 404 quer dizer que sua request não encontrou o Endpoint da api que está chamando, motivos podem ser vários, seu objeto que está passando não é válido, a url para request está errada. o `tipoCardapio` é null.

Comment: @Connection Acredito que não soube me explicar. O que desejo é saber como ler no cliente em C# o retorno das mensagens que colocamos junto com a resposta da API, por exemplo: 400 é código de BAD REQUEST, então retornamos `return BadRequest("Já existe um registro com esta descrição!");` Nos fóruns e blogs só se fala em como criar a API  mas como receber e interpretar as resposta não! 
Falam muito para usar o POSTMAN para testes, mas ele faz tudo sozinho, não vemos o código de como fazer para ter base.

Comment: Entendi, vou elaborar uma resposta que talvez possa ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso, eu recomendo fortemente a biblioteca [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) que já faz o trablaho de desserialização do objeto pra você, o que você precisa fazer é em seu cliente ter o Objeto semelhante, no caso seu:

```
public class TipoCardapio
{
   [Key]
   public int TipoId { get; set; }
   public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

Onde sua chamada seria algo com:

```
var client = new RestClient("URL");

var request = new RestRequest("Endpoint", Method.POST);
request.AddJsonBody(tipoCardatio); 

request.AddHeader("header", "value"); //Caso tenha algum Header

var response = client.Execute<TipoCardapio>(request);
```

Comment: Estou tentando usar somente os componentes do **.NET**.  Uma maneira de ler as respostas sem usar o **RestSharp** foi essa: `string responseBody = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` vejo o conteúdo desta mensagem de acordo com o **StatusCode** retornado. O **RestSharp** não conheço, mas vou pesquisar e aprimorar meus conhecimentos. Agradeço pela colaboração.

Comment: Isso mesmo, o retorno vem dentro do Content, o que você pode melhorar no seu código é abstrair o cabeçalho e a serialização fazendo uma Factory. Tem esse código muito bom de exemplo: https://github.com/TahirNaushad/Fiver.Api.HttpClient